# Question about Rotational Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

My notes on Transformations has the following formula for rotating a point **counter-clockwise** about the origin:

$\begin{align*}x^\prime&=x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta\\y^\prime&=x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta\end{align*}$

Why? And why does changing the direction mean that we change the signs before the sin values so that rotating a point around the origin **clockwise** can be found by:

$\begin{align*}x^\prime&=x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta\\y^\prime&=-x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta\end{align*}$

I am trying to work through an example, to rotate a point at (20, 0) $45^o$ clockwise, but I don't get the answer supplied by the notes.

**My Workings**

$\begin{align*}x^\prime&=20\cos(45) + 0\sin(45) = 10.51\\y^\prime&=-20\sin(45) + 0\cos(45) = -17.01\end{align*}$

but my notes give the answer as being:

$\begin{align*}x^\prime&=14.14\\y^\prime&=-14.14\end{align*}$

I don't want to just follow the formula (especially as I seem to be getting the wrong answer!). I really want to understand how the new position relates to the the addition and / or subtraction of sin and cos, but I don't have any intuitions about it.

Be grateful for any help.

Regards

Comment: For your second question: "rotate by $-\theta$ anticlockwise" is just another way of saying "rotate by $\theta$ clockwise". Note that the cosine is even and the sine is odd.

Comment: To evaluate $\sin(45^\circ)$ and $\cos(45^\circ)$, notice that $45^\circ$ is half of a right angle, and so is the angle in an isosceles right triangle.  Draw such a triangle, apply the Pythagorean theorem and use the fact that the smaller sides have the same length to conclude that $\cos(45^\circ)=\sin(45^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.  As for your evaluations, your calculator was in radian mode with degree inputs.

Comment: The cheater's way of motivating the rotation formulae: convert your Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates, add the rotation angle to the polar angle (corresponding to an anticlockwise rotation), and convert back, making use of the sum-of-angles formulae for trigonometric functions.

Comment: "your calculator was in radian mode with degree inputs." - it's a very common mistake to make. Be very careful with your manipulations if you insist on having to use degrees.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Need a bit of time to absorb what you're saying. I'll post back once I'm done.

Comment: Silly mistake having my calculator in radians. must make sure I don't do that in an exam.

Comment: Working above example with polar coordinates as suggested by @J.M. - Original polar coords = (20, $0^o$) subtract $45^o$ of rotation to give coords after rotation of (20, $315^o$). We know hypotenuse is 20, so x is 20 x cos(315) = 14.14, and y is 20 x sin(315) = -14.14. Good to think about it that way too. Many thanks for the explanation J.M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept that counterclockwise rotation by $\theta$ is a linear transformation, then the transformation is determined by its effect on the standard basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  So, let's look at where those vectors are sent.

The formulas come from the trigonometry going on, and I encourage you to draw this out at least once.  The vector $(1,0)$ points straight right along the $x$-axis, and after applying the transformation (rotating it by $\theta$), we get a new vector, still on the unit circle, with angle $\theta$ from the $x$-axis.  Essentially by definition of cosine and sine, this means that the new $x$ coordinate is $\cos(\theta)$, and the new $y$ coordinate is $\sin(\theta)$

Similarly, when we look at what happens to $(0,1)$ on that picture, we see that it gets sent to a vector with $x$-coordinate $-\sin(\theta)$ and $y$-coordinate $\cos(\theta)$.

That means that the transformation by $\theta$ degrees can be enacted by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)
\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Consequently, we can figure out what this transformation does to an arbitrary vector $(x,y)^T$ by left-multiplying it by this matrix to get (assuming I did this right)
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \cdot \cos(\theta) - y \cdot \sin(\theta)
\\
x \cdot \sin(\theta) + y \cdot \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

You could also check this in a less linear-algebra-ish way by just thinking about the rotation of the arbitrary vector to start with, but I think if you understand one way you'll be close to understanding the other.

Also, you can come up with the matrix for clockwise rotation in a similar way: it sends $(1,0)$ to $(\cos(\theta), -\sin(\theta))$ and sends $(0,1)$ to $(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$, so the corresponding matrix for the transformation is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)
\\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

and the result of applying this matrix to an arbitrary vector $(x,y)^T$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \cdot \cos(\theta) + y \cdot \sin(\theta)
\\
-x \cdot \sin(\theta) + y \cdot \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$

As far as why you're getting the wrong answer:  I strongly suspect that you're using a calculator that expects radian inputs to the trig functions.  You're probably plugging in 45 thinking that's 45 degrees, but it's interpreting it as 45 radians and giving you a weird answer.  Either try again using $\pi / 4$ radians, or change your calculator to work with degrees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's going to take me a while to work through it. I'll post back once I'm done. :)

Comment: Great Answer. I drew out the unit vector stuff and saw it working. Need to practice, practice, practice.